# Google Cloud Datalab Minimum System Requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Is it possible to create a google cloud datalab with f1-micro and 20GB of boot disk and 10GB of persistent disk?

Or is the minimum requirement, the default of n1-standard-1 and 200GB Standard Persistent Disk?

I tried to create a datalab instance with the following command:

datalab create --image-name practice --disk-size-gb 10 --idle-timeout "30m" --machine-type f1-micro practice

Although the VM is created, the datalab gets stuck at waiting for datalab to be available at localhost.
It works when I go with the default command of

datalab create practice

Any clarifications on this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the "--image-name practice" arg.  image-name is the Docker image to run on the VM, and needs to be either the Datalab provided one or a custom image you've created based off of that one.

This command should work: `datalab create --disk-size-gb 10 --idle-timeout "30m" --machine-type f1-micro practice` though you should note that this machine will be too small to run even some of the sample notebooks, and it's reduced size will cause a longer startup time.

I just tried it and startup was ~10 minutes.